# How to compare local master with remote master in Git?

Tags: git, remote-branch

I have made few changes in my remote code on github.com. Now, I need to compare my local master branch with origin. I am using below command to get the diff, but I don't see the diff on the terminal.

```
git diff master origin/master
```

If I use the below command, I can pull the latest from origin & I can see my changes pulled in.

```
git pull origin master
```

How can I see the diff in master & origin/master without using `git pull`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try running the following command:

```
git fetch 
git diff remote/branch
```

`git fetch` updates your tracking branches from the remote.

`git diff` will compare the remote branch with your local branch.